# Need help on weather and news info in Android

Tags: android

I am very new to Android and want to get weather info in a particular city and news headlines (rss feed?).
Please help me to get starting point for this.

Comment: Use some api and scrap it. Please refer http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/sax/parsing.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following networks provide weather api in JSON format. Its Free

[openweathermap.org/api](http://openweathermap.org/api)

[api.accuweather.com/](https://api.accuweather.com/)

[www.wunderground.com/weather/api/](http://www.wunderground.com/weather/api/)

Answer (score 0):

Yahoo Weather service provides updates via RSS.